# Order by multiple columns not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql :

```
GROUP BY dc.year, dc.month, d.user_id
ORDER BY dc.year DESC, d.user_id ASC
```

The result is :

```
UserId         Month            Year
 1               1              2020
 1               4              2020
 1               2              2020
 2               5              2019
 2               1              2019
```

Expected result :

```
UserId         Month            Year
 1               1              2020
 1               2              2020
 1               4              2020
 2               1              2019
 2               5              2019
```

But I want to order and by month not only by year. I tried like this `ORDER BY dc.year DESC, dc.month ASC, d. user_id ASC`, but not working as expected because I want to liste each user order by year desc and by month asc. Can you help me please ?

Comment: please select one rdms

Comment: @George . . . .Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't need `user_id` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Try this:

```
ORDER BY dc.year DESC, d.user_id, dc.month
```

Comment: I need, because I group bu user id, I tried you code but not working :(

Comment: Ok, changed my answer. Try it now

Comment: did you try switching d.user_id, dc.month? Like I just did in my edited answer?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to liste each user order by year desc and by month asc.

That describes:

```
ORDER BY d.user_id, dc.year DESC, dc.month
```

Comment: I want like this : year 2019 all users with all month order ASC, after that year 2018 all users with all month order ASC. Now I have for each user data for 2018 and 2019, after that another user :(

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY dc.user_id ASC, dc.month ASC, dc.year DESC;

Comment: hi dear friend, please write **Query** for helpful answer. and learn about , how does write a good answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the result as per your expected result. I have tried it from my end and getting the expected result.

```
GROUP BY dc.year, dc.month, d.user_id
order by dc.year DESC, dc.month asc, d.user_id asc
```

Check below the image with solution:

https://snipboard.io/NeAHB5.jpg